# Facebook share doesnt fetch the photo

Tags: facebook

Hello I`ve been struguling with this for a while.. and just can`t get my head around it.

I do have the meta tags required :

```
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.profsonstage.com" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="366418850196673">
    <meta property="og:title" content="ProfsOnStage"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="ProfsOnStage" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Welocme to ProfsOnStage Web Site" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.profsonstage.com" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.profsonstage.com" />
```

But when I try to use the share button facebook scraper doesnt fetch any data but the link.
When I check what the **scraper** sees I get :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script>function set_cookie(){var now = new Date();var time = now.getTime();time += 19360000 * 1000;now.setTime(time);document.cookie='beget=begetok'+'; expires='+now.toGMTString()+'; path=/';}set_cookie();location.reload();;</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I hope anyone can point me into the right direction to fix this. Checked a lot of similar questions but I was unable to find an answer regarding this issue.

Also I get this in my console log

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

And My APP urls are :

[www.profsonstage.com/](http://www.profsonstage.com/)
profsonstage.com/

I just don`t understand what is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its a hosting issue. If anyone get a problem like that contact your hosting provider.